# Dynamic sorting in NHibernate QueryOver using expressions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, expression, queryover

Given the following `QueryOver`:

```
UserProfile userProfileAlias = null;
Pegfile pegfileAlias = null;
var q = Session.QueryOver(() => pegfileAlias)
        .JoinAlias(() => pegfileAlias.UserProfile, () => userProfileAlias);
```

I would like to make the following statement dynamic, by swapping

```
q = q.OrderBy(() => userProfileAlias.Forename).Asc;
```

`(OrderBy(Expression<Func<object>>` or (`OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>>)`)

with

```
q = q.OrderBy(GetMemberExpression(userProfileAlias, "Forename")).Asc;
```

I borrowed from another post to get

```
private Expression<Func<object>> GetMemberExpression(UserProfile instance, string propertyName)
        {
            var arg = Expression.Constant(instance, typeof(UserProfile));
            var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, propertyName), typeof(UserProfile));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body);
            return lambda;
        }
```

but this isn't working, i get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'Pegfect.Domain.PegDudes.UserProfile'.
```

i think I probably need to match the following sig:

```
OrderBy(Expression<Func<UserProfile,object>>)
```

how to turn `GetMemberExpression` into returning that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your version doesn't work is the fact that NHibernate doesn't actually assign a value to the variable used as an alias in `JoinAlias`. It is merely a token that is being parsed. This means that it needs to be the exact *same variable*, when you want to use it elsewhere.
To achieve this, you need to save the alias expression and use its body to retrieve that variable:

```
UserProfile alias = null;
Expression<Func<object>> aliasExpression = () => alias;
session.QueryOver<Pegfile>()
       .JoinAlias(x => x.UserProfiles, aliasExpression)
       .OrderBy(GetMemberExpression(aliasExpression, "Forename")).Asc
       .List();

private Expression<Func<object>> GetMemberExpression(
                                     Expression<Func<object>> aliasExpression,
                                     string property)
{
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(aliasExpression.Body,
                                                 typeof(UserProfile), property);
    var body = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, typeof(object));

    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body);
    return result;
}
```