# Generic joined column ordering in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using fluent NHibernate in a large project. There's a lot of generic code written, including column ordering.

Suppose I have an QueryOver object, with fetch-joins already inside, and a list of objects describing which columns I'd like to order by and in what order, for instance on the joined column "Owner.Name" of the class contained in the QueryOver. How would I go about adding this order criteria to the QueryOver?

Comment: This answer to a similar question might be of interest : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14319092/1236044

Comment: There's some unsimilarities with this answer and my situation that make that unworkable. Firstly, I never use JoinAlias, but Fetch. Secondly, I never know what type the QueryOver implements, only that it inherits from a generic baseclass.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the method `-queryOverObject-.RootCriteria.CreateAlias(associationPath, alias)`.

For example, to sort by the joined property `Owner.Name`of an object, I just call `CreateAlias("Owner", "Owner")`, and can then do `.RootCriteria.AddOrder(Order.Desc("Owner.Name"))`.